# MS-SQL Server 2008 Trigger with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, triggers

I've added some simple triggers (after update) to my ms-sql server 2008 database which work perfect when I manually update recordsets in "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio".

But when I update recordsets with my PHP script (PHP 7, PDO), the recordsets get updated but the triggers won't fire.

I've already spent hours with google but didn't find a solution...

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Regards
M Badabum

The trigger create script:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIGGERNAME] ON [dbo].[TABLENAME]

   AFTER UPDATE

AS 

IF @@rowcount = 1

BEGIN    
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    IF ( not UPDATE (thenameofonefield)  )
    BEGIN    

  UPDATE f set last_update=GETDATE(), thenameofonefield=0 
  FROM 

  dbo.TABLENAME AS f     
  INNER JOIN inserted     
  AS i 

  ON f.id = i.id;    
    END    
END    
GO
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for your trigger.

Comment: Also, I would recommend starting a sql profiler instance before making update from PHP script and analyze that trace to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIGGERNAME] ON [dbo].[TABLENAME]

   AFTER UPDATE

AS 

IF @@rowcount = 1

BEGIN

 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;


    -- Insert statements for trigger here
 IF ( not UPDATE (thenameofonefield)  )
 BEGIN



  UPDATE f set last_update=GETDATE(), thenameofonefield=0 
  FROM 

  dbo.TABLENAME AS f 

  INNER JOIN inserted 

  AS i 

  ON f.id = i.id;


 END

END

GO

Comment: Hello!

I don't know why and how, but the trigger is now working also when updates are done via PHP. I tried it before the weekend and today it works...